# Getting GAE error message when deploying with basic static content app.yaml

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-deployment, app.yaml

I am getting the following error from GAE...

```
Line 6, column 15: Unable to find property 'static_files' on class: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppYaml$Handler
```

When deploying a simple static website from Codenvy to GAE.  I'm pretty sure I'm messing up something basic...  This is my current non-functional app.yaml...

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: java

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: static
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the right syntax for java.

Check the [guidelines](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml#Java_app_yaml_About_app_yaml)